# how to give time format in rails query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Mysql table one row =>

id = 1

time = "21:00" //datatype => TIME

name = "xyz"

while i am fetching the data

```
@person = @person.all
[#<persons id: 1, time: "2000-01-01 21:00:00, name: "xyz",  created_at: "2014-03-19 05:13:43", updated_at: "2014-03-19 05:13:43", creator_id: nil">
```

@person[0].time # 2000-01-01 21:00:00

It should be "21:00" Right?

Why i am getting "2000-01-01 21:00:00" output any suggestion ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@person[0].time` returns the Ruby [`Time`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Time.html) object for that value, which includes date. If you're outputting it directly to the console or browser window, Ruby is converting it to a default string representation of the `Time` object which, again, includes the date.

To format the time for display, you'll want to look at your [options for date/time formatting using Rails' internationalization API](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats).

Comment: Side note: I usually write `@person[0]` as `@person.first`. It's just more readable that way. Both ways work though.

Answer (score 2):

After fetching data from query, you can format to time for displaying:

fetch all the records:

```
@person = @person.all
```

format to time.

```
@person.first.time.strftime("%H:%M")
```

for getting more information about date and time formating [click here](http://apidock.com/ruby/Time/strftime)

Answer (score 0):

try using strftime - it lets you specify format

ie something like:

@person[0].time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y  %H:%M:%S")

Answer (score 0):

Changing datatype from TIME TO VARCHAR :

It is not good approach. I think you should consider all the case about time, there is a lot possibility where you required TIME object to other operation like date.

If you store hours and minutes in VARCHAR then you can not perform any operation like TIME object. please think about, if you required hours or date from database in future but you have store only hours and minutes in database, you did not store (TIME Object)it, then it will be considered bad approach and failure.

you store TIME at the place of hours and minutes then It is good cause for future perspective.

If you store time object then you are store additional information with hours and minutes. If you will required Date, time, hours, minutes and even seconds then you can calculate by time formating.

If you store time then there is only one extra effort time formating that is negligible in perspective of performance.

To store TIME Object instead of hours and minutes in string format is always better.